# difference of 2 dates coming out wrong

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am changing the row color of my gridview based on how many days the task is from today. But it is not working
date1 is todays date
and date2 is the due date of the task.

**also when i sort i click on the column headers to sort, the rows change colors**

```
Protected Sub GridView6_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs)
    Dim date1 As Date
    date1 = Date.Now

    Dim date2 As Date

    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView6.Rows
        Dim ddate As Label = CType(row.FindControl("label1"), Label)
        date2 = Date.Parse(ddate.Text)

        Dim ts As TimeSpan = date2.Subtract(date1)
        Dim days As Integer = ts.TotalDays



        If days <= 14 Then
            e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        ElseIf days > 14 And ts.Days < 30 Then
            e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue
        ElseIf days >= 30 Then
            e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen
        End If



    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Have you stepped through this in the debugger? Confirm that date2 and date1 have the values you think they do, and see what the value of ts.Days is. If you see a discrepancy, update your question with more info.

Comment: i updated the code in my entry to match my grid

Comment: Whatever `label1` is, are you sure that it's a parsable date and that you are using the correct `CultureInfo` to parse the given string?

Comment: for 3/3/2011 in debug ts is 24 but the color is wrong, red should be less than 14

Comment: according to the debugger the dates are subtracting correctly and both days and ts.totaldays match and are correct but the colors are wrong

Comment: I also noticed when i sort my gridview the rows change colors, randomly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took a while, but eventually I spotted it.

You are looping through every row, then only updating the one being databound!

Get rid of your foreach row in grid.Rows, and just work on the row in e.Row.

Your code should be this:

```
Protected Sub GridView6_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs)     
  Dim date1 As Date     
  date1 = Date.Now      
  Dim date2 As Date      

  Dim ddate As Label = CType(e.Row.FindControl("label1"), Label)         
  date2 = Date.Parse(ddate.Text)          
  Dim ts As TimeSpan = date2.Subtract(date1)         
  Dim days As Integer = ts.TotalDays            
  If days <= 14 Then             
    e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red         
  ElseIf days > 14 And ts.Days < 30 Then 
    e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue         
  ElseIf days >= 30 Then 
    e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen         
End If         
End Sub
```

Comment: hmm i tried this but i get a ddate is not set to an instance of an object

Comment: date2 = Date.Parse(ddate.Text)

Comment: Are you sure your label is called `label1`?

Answer (score 0):

You might want `TotalDays` from the `TimeSpan`.

Comment: hmm i tryed it too and still nothing ill show a copy of my grid

Comment: Are you updating `days` or doing it directly in your `If`?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
date1 = Date.Now
```

with

```
date1 = Date.Now.Date
```

Date.Now contains the time part also. It seems from the context that, you are interested only of date difference ,not considering the time.